# How to alter field values on a display page?

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I am trying to alter field values in a page display.  I can get the field values easily using [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7), but depending on the values of other fields, I may need to manipulate the text and/or display based on some PHP logic in my template file.  I am trying to do it using either [hook_page_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) or [hook_preprocess_HOOK()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7).

I cannot get the text to be altered when the page is displayed using `hook_page_alter()` or `hook_preprocess_HOOK()`.  I can confirm those 2 functions are working and that I can pull the values from the DB (`$page['content']`), but I cannot override the variable to set them.  For example:

```
function standard_submission_page_alter(&$page) {
    $node = menu_get_object();
    $page['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$node->nid]['field_title_nickname']['#items'][0]['value'] = 'A new nickname title!';
}

function standard_submission_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    $vars['node']->field_title_nickname['und'][0]['value'] = 'A new nickname title 2x';
}
```

Any ideas on why my altering of this `field_title_nickname` text field value isn't being accepted and displayed?  It keeps reverting back to whatever is originally in the database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I need to manipulate the text and/or display based on some PHP logic, I would do it using [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) in a custom module, not in a template file.

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL) {
    if( $view_mode == 'full' ){
        if( some conditions here ){
            $node->content['field_title_nickname'] = array(
                '#markup' => '<div>A new nickname title 2x</div>'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately hook_node_view() doesn't even run in my module.  Even something as simple as die() inside hook_node_view() should cause a white screen of death, but that doesn't even get run.  I have also tried hook_view, and that doesn't do anything either.  And yes, I did remember to clear all caches and disable and reenable my module every time a change is made.  I am trying to alter a content type I made in Drupal.  My module does not create a new content type.  Does this matter?

Comment: Duh!  My bad. It's called hook_node_VIEW for a reason.  I kept checking on the entry form to add a new content. When I view an existing content then the hook_node_view is being invoked and working.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by implementing template_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) in your template.php

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    if ($node->type == 'car') {
      if($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_price') {
        $variables['items']['0']['#markup'] = $new_value; //new value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check here: http://tassaf.moriamedia.com/change-field-value-in-node-view/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

If use [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) implement [hook_ds_pre_render_alter()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ds!ds.api.php/function/hook_ds_pre_render_alter/7) to alter entity render array.

Example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ds_pre_render_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_ds_pre_render_alter(&$layout_render_array, $context, &$vars) {
  $entity_type = $context['entity_type'];
  if ($entity_type == 'node') {
    $layout_render_array['ds_content']['Foo']['#markup'] = 'Bar';
  }
}
```